# Lithium PHP Framework - Seeding Database?

Tags: php, mongodb, seed, lithium, database

What is the best way to seed a MongoDB database using Lithium PHP Framework, like in Ruby on Rails:

```
rake db:seed
```

Thanks!

Comment: What I ended up doing was creating a special action in an admin controller that seeded the database, and another to delete everything in the system. Not elegant, I know, but it works flawlessly and everyone on the team was happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is:

- [li3_fixtures](https://github.com/daschl/li3_fixtures) for the tests.

Which you can reuse to create your `li3 seed` command.